# Problem with split()

Tags: php, split

when I try to launch my PHP script, I get this error: [error] [client ::1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/loterija.php on line 16

I think the problem is with split() function. Here's the code:

```
<?php

$arr = array();

if(isset($_POST['roll'])):

echo "Lucky numbers: " . '<br />';

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $arr[] = rand(1, 100);
}

$post = $_POST['numbers'];

echo '<br />' . "Your numbers: " . '<br />'; 
$split = split(" ", $post, 5);   

endif;




?>


<html>
<head>
<title>Lottery Script</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="#" method="post">

Enter five numbers: <input type="text" name="numbers" />
<input type="submit" name="roll" value="Roll!" />

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no syntax error in this code, check that this is actually the one you're having problem with

Comment: Why are you doing this: `'<br />' . "Your numbers: " . '<br />'` when you can do this: `'<br />Your numbers: <br />'`?

Comment: Works alright for me. Are you sure the problem doesn't lie elsewhere, e.g. is your webserver referring to an old version of the file or something?

Comment: btw, you don't have to put your html tags into separate strings, you can simply write `echo <br />Your Numbers: <br />';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split is DEPRECATED, use explode. What version of PHP are you using. If it's 5.0 or above, use explode.

I am assuming you are separating by space.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I have the same problem with explode.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use `split()` and it has been deprecated.
Just do this: `$split = explode(" ", $post);`

Answer (score 0):

Consider `preg_split` or `explode`.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php